# POST method in RestClient using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I am trying to post values using RestClient. It always shows the following error.

> RestClient::BadRequest (400 Bad Request):

Tried all the answers in SO. Nothing helped. This is my code.

> response = RestClient.post "http://192.72.114.66/WDSTEST_WS/WDS_SERVICE.svc/companymaster/Add",{"CompanyMaster":{"Address1":"Raja Street cbe","BussinessProfile":"lll","City":"statee","CompanyID":24,"CompanyName":"Ramu Metall","CreatedBy":138,"Email":"abcd@gmail.com","IsActive":true,"LandLine":"435435","MobileNumber1":"8787871221","ModifiedBy":138,"PinCode":0,"Remarks":"null","State":"null","TonnageKM":"0","TotalInsurableGoodValueForPreviousYear":0.00,"TotalInsurableGoodValuePerYear":0.00,"TotalTransportationCostForPreviousYear":0.00,"TotalTransportationCostPerYear":0.00,"TotalTransportedWeightPerYear":0.00,"Website":"null"}}, headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}

This is just a dummy data.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved it. There was a mistake in format. The correct format is,

```
response = RestClient.post "http://192.72.114.66/WDSTEST_WS/WDS_SERVICE.svc/companymaster/Add", {"CompanyMaster": {"Address1":"Ganapathy","Address2":"Coimbatore","BussinessProfile":"null","City":"null","CompanyID":25,"CompanyName":"Priya agency","CreatedBy":138,"CreatedDate":"19-06-2015 11:01:41","Email":"poombavai@gmail.com","IsActive":true,"LandLine":"06654-3422412","MobileNumber1":"9568678567","ModifiedBy":138,"PinCode":643434,"Remarks":"null","TonnageKM":"122","Website":"www.poombavai.com"}}.to_json, :content_type => "application/json"
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If you mark this answer as "Accepted", it will let folks know you're all set.